# Reading a .csv file using string.split method

Tags: java, string, jakarta-ee, servlets, csv

I have a .csv file which consists entry in following format:-

```
question,option1,option2,option3,option4,answer
```

I want to read this .csv file and insert data in a table.
I am using string.split method for doing this and it works fine 
for eg:-

```
   String a="hi,a,b,c,d,e";
    String[] b=a.split(",");

output is:-
b[0]=hi
b[1]=a
b[2]=b
b[3]=c
b[4]=d
b[5]=e
```

but when i use space in between it gives me an error:
for eg:-

```
String a="hi how are you,a,b,c,d,e";
String[] b=a.split(",");
```

I am using this concept in a servlet which stores the values in database.
Here is the servlet code:-

```
 File file=new File(path2);
        Scanner inputstream=new Scanner(file);
        while(inputstream.hasNext()){
            String data=inputstream.next();
            String[] val=data.split(",");
            String sql4="insert into "+name+"(question,option1,option2,option3,option4,answer) values('"+val[0]+"','"+val[1]+"','"+val[2]+"','"+val[3]+"','"+val[4]+"','"+val[5]+"')";
            s.execute(sql4);
        }
```

I am getting Array index out of bound exception.

Please help.

Thankyou. :)

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: Array index out of bound

Comment: Show us more code. What you show is valid. I guess the problem comes when you start to iterate on your array.

Comment: I don't get the error. Make sure you don't have a line with less than 6 comma separated items. You probably are trying to get `b[5]` of a line that does not have that many items. Either catch the exception or check that there are 6 items in the array before indexing into it.

Comment: Are you sure there are always 5 options in your csv? BTW, concatened queries are evil. Consider prepared statements in order to avoid SQL injections.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle You can see my code i just added by editing question.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle Yes,It is a mcq test.So one for question,4 for options and 1 for answer.Thankyou

Comment: @saumyaraj I am sure that you got a problem with one of the lines (probably header or footer of your CSV). Can you please trace each line and the corresponding array size ?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle My csv file has correct format of 6 strings seperated by comma but there are many entries and i have used a new line for them so is it the cause of problem?
For eg:-
first que,b,c,d,e,b
second que,b,c,d,e,b
third que,b,c,d,e,b
fourth que,b,c,d,e,b
fifth que,b,c,d,e,b

Comment: @saumyaraj The only way to know where to problem comes from is to place a break point on the problmematic line. You will then see which line causes the problem and what is its content.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle The breakpoint is the insert statement in my code above.

Comment: @saumyaraj I tried and found the problem : By default, ` ` is one of the delimiters. Hence, having spaces in your lines makes the Scanner split it into small lines with very few items. See my answer.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle So if I am not wrong the problem was that the scanner was taking the first word as a line. Is it?

Comment: @saumyaraj Yes : If you had only characters separated with non-whitespace characters, it would have worked. But as soon as you have a whitespace character, the Scanner considers it by default as a new token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `space` is one of the delimiters. This makes you have tons of small arrays instead of arrays with exactly 5 elements. Hence your ArrayOutOfBounds if you assumed that every line contained exactly 5 elements.

Specify the delimiter like this :

```
Scanner inputstream=new Scanner(file);
inputstream.useDelimiter("\n");
```

Edit : This code shows you the default delimiter :

```
Scanner inputstream=new Scanner(file);
System.out.println("Delimiter : "+inputstream.delimiter().toString());
```

Output :

```
\p{javaWhitespace}+
```

This includes (according to javadoc of [Character#isWhiteSpace(char ch)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace%28char%29)):

- It is a Unicode space character (SPACE_SEPARATOR, LINE_SEPARATOR, or PARAGRAPH_SEPARATOR) but is not also a non-breaking space ( '\u005Cu00A0', '\u005Cu2007', '\u005Cu202F').
- It is '\u005Ct', U+0009 HORIZONTAL TABULATION.
- It is '\u005Cn', U+000A LINE FEED.
- It is '\u005Cu000B', U+000B VERTICAL TABULATION.
- It is '\u005Cf', U+000C FORM FEED.
- It is '\u005Cr', U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN.
- It is '\u005Cu001C', U+001C FILE SEPARATOR.
- It is '\u005Cu001D', U+001D GROUP SEPARATOR.
- It is '\u005Cu001E', U+001E RECORD SEPARATOR.
- It is '\u005Cu001F', U+001F UNIT SEPARATOR.

Comment: @saumyaraj My pleasure : today, I learnt something about Scanners ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
        File file = new File(path2);
    String data = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
    String[] val = data.split(",");
    String sql4 = "insert into " + name + "(question,option1,option2,option3,option4,answer) values('" + val[0] + "','" + val[1] + "','" + val[2] + "','"
            + val[3] + "','" + val[4] + "','" + val[5] + "')";
    s.execute(sql4);
```

If you are iterating over the stream than you should split the string after completely reading the stream . splitting it in every cycle may not result same output since you may not have full data yet.

More explanation on use of scanner class to convert to string - [Stupid Scanner Tricks](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/pat/archive/2004/10/stupid_scanner_1.html)

Answer (score 0):

I don´t see where's the error. Itsearches for the delimiter you pass as parameter (','), so it splits your string in:

```
b[0]=hi how are you
b[1]=a
b[2]=b
b[3]=c
b[4]=d
b[5]=e
```

Comment: please refer to the servlet code i just added.My values is not getting in table.

Comment: have you tried setting a breakpoint and evaluating what each of the val items are at the time of checking?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no problem with code. It is most likely with your CSV file. 
Also, let me take a very silly guess and confirm that when changing your test case in CSV format, you aren't replacing a comma with space, are you...!? 
I know i am taking a very silly guess, but trust me, i have done really silly things and had only myself to blame for it :D

*P.S: I am assuming you manually changed the data in CSV 'once'. Please ignore if not the case.*

Comment: Nope.Right now for testing i wrote my csv file with 6 strings in one line.